# Sort the highest values ​by combining data sets

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 df8 <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hirenvadher954/Worldometers- 
 Scraping/master/countries.csv',
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)

    df %>% 
   left_join(df8, by = c("countryName" = "country_name")) %>% 
   mutate(population = as.numeric(str_remove_all(population, ","))) %>% 
    group_by(countryName) %>% 
     group_by(countryName) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  summarize(population = sum(population, na.rm = TRUE),
        confirmed = sum(confirmed, na.rm = TRUE),
        recovered = sum(recovered, na.rm = TRUE),
        death = sum(death, na.rm = TRUE),
        death_prop = paste0(as.character(death), "/", as.character(population)),
        confirmed_prop = paste0(as.character(confirmed), "/", as.character(population)),
        recovered_prop = paste0(as.character(recovered), "/", as.character(population)),
        )
```

population / death ratio is calculated in this code.

what I want to do is
Finding 10 countries with the highest population / death ratio.

as output;

`counrtyName     death     population      rate`

`İtaly           19000     50000000000     19/50000000`

`spain           17000     60000000000     17/60000000`

`....`

`.....`

`....`

`....`

`....`
The examples I have given are not real data.

examples do not reflect reality.

Comment: You could try to  calculate the rate with a `mutate(rate = death/population)` call and the top ten using `dplyr::top_n(rate)`

Comment: how so ? where should i add @Peter